# Escape from a recursive subroutine

Tags: perl

I want my code to escape from a recursive subroutine after a specific iterations

This is my my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;

&sub();

my $count = 0;
sub sub
{
    if ( $count lt 1 )
    {
        print "This statment is visible \n";
        $count++;
        &sub();
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

THis gives below output and I am happy with that:

```
This statment is visible
```

But If I use the `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`, then it gives me hte output but also gives me a warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value $count in string lt at sub.pl line 9.
This statment is visible
```

**Quistion 1:** How to get rid of above warning.

Now, Above code was my test code and I want to apply the same logic to my actual code below:

In short, I want to resolve a `hostname` to its `IP address`. If it doesn't work, then i want to append the `domain name (.my.company.net)` to the `hostname` and then try the name resoltuion.

However, my above code (in some cases, don't know why) goes into infinite deep recursion and eats up the whole memory. My VM becomes unresponsive and I have to reboot it to get it back working.

Hence, I want to break free from the recursive sub after one iteration rather than doing infinite recursion.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $IP = to_ip("abcdefgh");
print $IP."\n";

my $count = 0;
sub to_ip
{
    if ( $count lt 1 )
    {
        use Socket;
        my $hostname    = shift;
        my $packed_ip   = gethostbyname($hostname);
        if ( defined $packed_ip )
        {
            sprintf inet_ntoa($packed_ip);
        }
        else
        {
            $hostname .= ".my.company.net";
            to_ip($hostname);
        }
        $count++;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Aobve code gives me below warning and then again get stuck. I have to reboot hte VM to get it back on.

```
Useless use of sprintf in void context at get_deleted_list.pl line 98.
```

please ignore the line number in above warning. it is referring to the `sprintf` in my sub

**Question 2:** How to break free from my sub after one iteration. I dont care whether I get the result from the sub but I want to come out of it after one iteration.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it should also warn something like `Deep recursion at ...`.

Comment: thats right. The error said something about `deep recursion at line 101...`

Comment: "I have a problem. I know, I'll use recursion! Now I have 2 problems. I know, I'll use recursion! ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple loop-based solution would be more straightforward:

```
sub to_ip
{
  use Socket;
  my $hostname = shift;
  for my $suffix ("", ".my.company.net") {
    my $packed_ip = gethostbyname("$hostname$suffix");
    next unless defined $packed_ip;
    return sprintf inet_ntoa($packed_ip);
  }
 }
```

This simply tries all the alternatives in order until one succeeds, at which point it returns the desired string. (BTW, is `sprintf` really necessary here?). If you fall out of the loop without a successful call to `gethostbyname`, you return undef implicitly.

Comment: I agree about the loop. It's a good improvement. I was thinking the same thing, but wanted to fix the problem first.

Comment: Also, why `continue` and not `last`? Shouldn't `continue` work with `given .. when`? http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html

Comment: I don't know about interaction with `given..when`; my Perl work was confined to code compatible with 5.8.

Comment: +1 for a different approach. Also, I think it should be `next` instead of `continue`

Comment: Oh, right. I've been doing a lot more Python than Perl lately. You'd think the question about `given...when` would have alerted me to that.

Comment: `next` lets me return from inside the loop when a call to `gethostbyname` succeeds, and return `undef` when all calls fail and I exit the loop normally. With `last`, I'd have to declare `$packed_ip` outside the loop, then test if it is defined after the loop to decide what to return.  [new version of old comment to replace `continue` with `next`]

Answer (score 3):

Answer to **question 1**: Place the `my $count` **above** the subroutine call:

```
my $count = 0;
&sub();

sub sub
{
  # ...
}
```

`$count` is not declared when you are calling the sub. It cannot be used to compare it to something else, thus the warning.  Without warnings, Perl will still do the command with the `$count` in it, but it won't complain.

**Question 2**:

First, place `$count` above the subroutine call. Your [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) warning is telling you that you are calling `sprintf` without using the return value. `sprintf` formats a string and returns it. If you want to output that string, you could say `print sprintf $foo`, or simply use [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html).

Once you've made both changes, it will work without running in an endless loop. At least it does for me.

One other thing: Move the `use Socket` outside of the sub, to the very top. It is evaluated at compile time, so it will be loaded anyway. If you want it to only load if you come its way, use `require Socket` and `Socket::inet_ntoa($packed_ip)` instead.

```
use strict; use warnings;
# use Socket;

my $count = 0;
my $IP = to_ip("abcdefgh");
print $IP. "\n";

sub to_ip {
  if ( $count lt 1 ) {
    my $hostname  = shift;
    my $packed_ip = gethostbyname($hostname);
    if ( defined $packed_ip ) {
      require Socket;                       # instead of use
      print Socket::inet_ntoa($packed_ip);
    } else {
      $hostname .= ".my.company.net";
      to_ip($hostname);
    }
    $count++;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. thanks for the Question 1 Answer. Any thoughts around Question 2 ??

Comment: I am working on your suggestion. will post my update soon. Thanks.

Comment: many thanks for your time and the approach you have suggested. The solution given by @chepner is fitting perfectly for me. I wish I could accept more than one answer/s.